# Mostrar clientes a los que tienes acceso según tu municipio

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas tardes quiero mostrar los clientes que tengo habilitados en mi municipio(ciudad) y mi usuario, pero no se como puedo comprobar, voy a mostrar las tablas.

**Mi tabla clientes**

| id | name | apellidos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nombre1 | Apellidos2 |
| 2 | Nombre2 | Apellidos2 |

**Mi tabla ubicacions**

| id | cliente_id | poblacion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 865 |
| 2 | 2 | 866 |
| 2 | 3 | 870 |

**Mi tabla comercial accesos**

| id | admin_id | municipio_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 865 |
| 2 | 5 | 870 //municipio_id es lo que enlaza con poblacion de la tabla ubicacions |

**En mi controlador**

```
$clientes = Cliente::where('tipo_cliente', 0)->get();
```

El admin_id lo comprobaria con `auth()->user()->id`

La idea es que si yo admin_id 5 estoy logueado y entro mi vista de clientes, quiero que se vean todos ellos que tengo acceso por su municipio(ciudad), eso es posible?

Intento pensar con ralaciones pero no se me ocurre como.

---

Con Joins si que se hacerlo, lo pongo por si alguien me puede ayudar a hacerlo con relaciones.

```
$clientes = Cliente::join('ubicacions', 'clientes.id', 'ubicacions.cliente_id')
     ->join('comercial_accesos', 'comercial_accesos.municipio_id', 'ubicacions.poblacion')
     ->where('comercial_accesos.admin_id', auth()->user()->id)
     ->where('clientes.tipo_cliente', 0)
     ->get();
```

Comment: Con una M:N (`belongsToMany`) deberías poder relacionar clientes y comercial access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Cliente` hasMany `Ubicacion` (`ubicacions.client_id` = `clientes.id`)
- `CommercialAccess` hasMany `Ubicacion` (`ubicacions.poblacion` = `commercial_accesses.municipio_id`)
- => `Cliente` belongsToMany `CommercialAccess` (y vice versa)

```php
# Cliente.php

public function commercial_accesses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
                    ComercialAccess::class,
                    'ubicacions',
                    'cliente_id',
                    'poblacion',
                    'id',
                    'municicpio_id',
                )
                ->using(Ubicacion::class);
}
```

```php
Cliente::whereHas('commercial_acceses', fn ($ca) => $ca->where('admin_id', 5))->get();

// o
Cliente::whereHas('commercial_acceses', fnunction ($ca) { $ca->where('admin_id', 5); })->get();
```

Comment: Hola y gracias @IGP esta noche lo pruebo sin falta